# In a time series study, how many time points are enough for unit root test

Tags: r, time-series, unit-root

I'm keeping some fish for toxicity test and will analyze specific parameter after exposing toxicants. I am keeping the fish in normal condition and check the parameter daily as "baseline". I plan to run unit root test to confirm whether there is change after toxicant exposure. However, I'm not quite sure how long the "baseline" data I need to obtain will considered "enough" for the upcoming analysis. Anyone may provide me hints? Thank you.